# Erlang : Which is more efficient in this scenario - using try catch or case statements?

Tags: erlang, performance

Say I have some function fn1() in Erlang which returns `{ok, Result}` if the function was executed successfully and `{error, "ErrorReason"}` if there was an error.

Now in another function fn2() I call fn1() and I need to check the result of fn1 and proceed only if it is `{ok, Result}`.

I figured, I can do this using either case or try catch. But **Efficiency** is my main concern and I'd like to know which of the two methods below is more efficient:

**`try-catch` Method**

```
fn2() ->
   try
      {ok, Result} = fn1(),
      %Do something with Result
      ok
   catch
      throw:Term -> Term;
      exit:Reason -> {exit, Reason};
      error:Reason -> {error,{Reason,erlang:get_stacktrace()}}
   end.
```

**`case` Method**

```
fn2() ->
   Res = fn1(),
   case Res of
      {ok, Result} -> 
         %Do something with Result
         ok;
      {error, Reason} ->
         Reason
   end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case method will be more efficient, as it simply pattern matches, and does not involve building a call stack and stuff.

In both examples you are about to handle the "error" locally, so there is no point in the try catch.What you might see sometimes is something like:

```
fn2() ->
  {ok, Result} = fn1(),
  %Do stuff with Result
  ok.
```

Here the intention is that you make fn2() throw a badmatch, if fn1() did not return ok. You let someone else "above" handle the problem. E.g. this might kill your process, and make your supervisor create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, that was enlightening! :)

Answer (score 10):

You really want to try and avoid try/catch like the plague. It is a very uncommon idiom in Erlang - really only used in a couple of special cases:

- where you are checking user-supplied
  input and you have no guarantees that
  it will be 'correct'
- where you have something which is
  deeply nested and the cost of
  unrolling it on an error condition
  is too expensive

  - like mensia transactions
  - or in parser/lexer's

Try/catch is essential in languages like C++ where the application is unstable in the presence or errors, but Erlang is stable in those circumstances - the process crashes but doens't bring the system down.

You should programme the happy path, match return values and if the application deviates from what you expect then ***let it crash***. The crash tells you you have a problem and tells you to fix it.

The problem with try/catch is that it can simply mask the problem, or even worse, move the eventual crash away from where it should happen (inside the expression you have wrapped) and make it appear elsewhere - where your programming logic expects it to have suceeded = which makes debugging much harder.

Programming the happy path and letting it crash is very disconcerting the first time you do it, it feels like going out with no clothes on, but actually you get used to it real quick :)

Comment: This is probably the best advice I've read about "Let it crash" philosophy

Answer (score 4):

You should always measure to find things like this out.

Your code also does not do what you think it does.

```
-module(glurk).
-compile(export_all).

fn2() ->
   try
      {ok, Result} = fn1(),
      %Do something with Result
      ok
   catch
      throw:Term -> Term;
      exit:Reason -> {exit, Reason};
      error:Reason -> {error,{Reason,erlang:get_stacktrace()}}
   end.

fn1() ->
    {error, a}.
```

Try this out:

```
 c(glurk).   
./glurk.erl:6: Warning: variable 'Result' is unused
{ok,glurk}
16> glurk:fn2().
{error,{{badmatch,{error,a}},
        [{glurk,fn2,0},
         {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
         {shell,exprs,6},
         {shell,eval_exprs,6},
         {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
```

This is because fn1 did not raise an exception
it gebnerated a normal retyurn value {error, a} which
does not pattern match against {ok, Result}

The first version of your code works with a function that either returns a normal value
or raises an exception - you have to write it like this:

```
fn1(....) ->
     ...
     %% success case
     Val;

     %% failure case
     throw(...) | exit(...) | error(...)
```

You can't just pump the same function into fn1 and fn2.

If you had the case where the called function had to escape from a deep recursion
then the first method would be more efficient than the second - since you could
immediately exit from a deep recursion by saying throw(...).

So the answer depends upon the nature of the function that you are calling.

Code should always be optimised for beauty and not efficiency - since you have
to maintain the stuff - then it should only be optimised in the rare cases
where it is not fast enough. What needs to be optimised should be identified
by measuring the program (you will always be surprised here :-)

Me, I'd write

```
{ok,Result} = ...
```

Actually your first code has a more subtle error

```
 fn2() ->
   try
      {ok, Result} = fn1(),
      %Do something with Result
      ok
   catch
      throw:Term -> Term;
      exit:Reason -> {exit, Reason};
      error:Reason -> {error,{Reason,erlang:get_stacktrace()}}
   end.
```

Think about this. The caught error cases do not themselves handle the error
they just return tuples like {exit, Reason} or {error, Reason} this means that the
next layer up (ie the caller of fn2) will also have to mess around checking
error returns - if this is repeated at all levels the code will be a mess.

The "erlang" way is to have one try-catch at the top of the program and just terminate
abruptly with exit(Why) if an error occurs.

In fact often you should not even do this - you should link your process to another process
then the offending process will die and "the other processes will fix the error".

The exception propagates up the call stack and flies over to the linked processes
for treatment. So we have two types of processes - ones that have no inbuilt error handling
and processes that only do error handling.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, irrespective of what is more efficient, you should definitely use the `case` alternative as it more succinctly describes what is going on. Your `fn1()` here return a value indicating if there is a successful value or an error. In the `case` version you directly match against this, while in the `try` version you match against the success value which will generate an error if an error was returned. It is unnecessarily convoluted and hides what is going on so it is bad programming style and should be avoided.

And as Gordon has already pointed out having a `try` there will catch more errors than you probably intend and may so mask other *real* errors which you should see.

The `case` will also be faster here, but the difference is probably small. The clarity, succinctness and good programming style is much more important!

Answer (score 0):

The case will always be more efficient, but the difference is small and it's more important what makes more sense in your particular case. Especially, which approach produces more understandable code. See this benchmark:

```
%% Results:
%% 7> errors:run_normal(100).
%% {9,ok}
%% 8> errors:run_normal(1000).
%% {107,ok}
%% 9> errors:run_normal(10000).
%% {856,ok}
%% 10> errors:run_normal(1000, 10).
%% {263,ok}
%% 11> errors:run_wcatch(10000).
%% {2379,ok}
%% 12> errors:run_wcatch(1000, 10).
%% {401,ok}
%% 18> errors:run_normal_cplx(10000, 50).
%% {7910,ok}
%% 19> errors:run_wcatch_cplx(10000, 50).
%% {10222,ok}
```

```erlang
-module(errors).

-compile(export_all).

run_normal(Iterations) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> normal() end).

run_normal(Iterations, Level) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> deepnormal(Level) end).

run_wcatch(Iterations) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> wcatch() end).

run_wcatch(Iterations, Level) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> deepwcatch(Level) end).

run_normal_cplx(Iterations) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> normal_complex() end).

run_normal_cplx(Iterations, Level) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> deepnormal_complex(Level) end).

run_wcatch_cplx(Iterations) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> wcatch_complex() end).

run_wcatch_cplx(Iterations, Level) ->
    get_result(Iterations, fun() -> deepwcatch_complex(Level) end).

%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

get_result(Iterations, Fun) ->
    timer:tc(fun() -> run(Iterations, Fun) end).

run(0, _Fun) ->
    ok;
run(Iterations, Fun) ->
    Fun(),
    run(Iterations - 1, Fun).

%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

normal() ->
    case foo(atom) of
        {ok, atom} -> ok;
        {error, atom} -> ok
    end.

normal_complex() ->
    case foo_cplx() of
        {ok, Res} -> Res;
        {error, Res} -> Res
    end.

deepnormal(Level) ->
    case deepfoo(atom, Level) of
        {ok, atom} -> ok;
        {error, atom} -> ok
    end.

deepnormal_complex(Level) ->
    case deepfoo_cplx(Level) of
        {ok, Res} -> Res;
        {error, Res} -> Res
    end.

wcatch() ->
    try
        {ok, atom} = foothrow(atom)
    catch
        throw:{error, atom} -> ok
    end.

wcatch_complex() ->
    try
        {ok, _Res} = foothrow_cplx()
    catch
        throw:{error, Res} -> Res
    end.

deepwcatch(Level) ->
    try
        {ok, atom} = deepfoothrow(atom, Level)
    catch
        throw:{error, atom} -> ok
    end.

deepwcatch_complex(Level) ->
    try
        {ok, _Res} = deepfoothrow_cplx(Level)
    catch
        throw:{error, Res} -> Res
    end.

%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

foo(Arg) -> {error, Arg}.

foothrow(Arg) -> throw({error, Arg}).

deepfoo(Arg, 0) -> {error, Arg};
deepfoo(Arg, Level) -> deepfoo(Arg, Level - 1).

deepfoothrow(Arg, 0) -> throw({error, Arg});
deepfoothrow(Arg, Level) -> deepfoothrow(Arg, Level - 1).


foo_cplx() -> {error, {<<"Some">>, "Complex", data}}.

foothrow_cplx() -> throw({error, {<<"Some">>, "Complex", data}}).

deepfoo_cplx(0) -> {error, {<<"Some">>, "Complex", data}};
deepfoo_cplx(Level) -> deepfoo_cplx(Level - 1).

deepfoothrow_cplx(0) -> throw({error, {<<"Some">>, "Complex", data}});
deepfoothrow_cplx(Level) -> deepfoothrow_cplx(Level - 1).
```